Does $e^{A}$ being orthogonal imply $A$ is anti-symmetric?
Suppose $A$ is a real anti-symmetric matrix, that is $A^{T} = -A$. By the definition of the matrix function $e^{A}$, we have $(e^{A})^{T} = e^{A^{T}} = e^{-A}$. Since $A$ and $-A$ are commutative, we have $e^{A}(e^{A})^{T} = (e^{A})^{T}e^{A} = I$. Thus $e^{A}$ is an orthogonal matrix.
Now on the contrary, if $e^{A}$ is an orthogonal matrix where $A$ is a real matrix, does this imply that $A$ is anti-symmetric? This time we do not know if $A$ and $A^{T}$ are commutative so it seems that we can not directly use the conclusion $e^{A + B} = e^{A}e^{B}$ for $AB = BA$.

@geetha290krm I am mainly concerned about the case of real matrices. Does this is true for real matrices?

It implies that all eigenvalues of $A$ are purely imaginary

You at least have that if $M$ is orthogonal then $M = e^B$ for some skew-symmetric $B$.

Set
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 4\pi \\ 
                      -\pi & 0
\end{array} \right). 
$$
Then $A$ is not antisymmetric but
$$
\exp(A)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 
                      0 & 1
\end{array} \right).
$$
Note that the eigenvalues are $\pm 2\pi i$. See also here:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=MatrixExp%28%5B%5B0%2C4*pi%5D%2C%5B-pi%2C0%5D%5D%29
